# How can move writing in the centre in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites

How can I move CSM writing to the middle.

[image]

Comment: CSM is the site name, right?

Comment: @Aashirya Yes :)

Comment: @Aashirya I found the code <style>
.ms-core-pageTitle
{
        text-align: center;
}
</style>

Answer (score 0):

Control the page name position using **margin-left** in Script editor web part

```
.ms-belltown-pageName, .ms-belltown-pageName a
{
    margin-left: 200px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: How would I put it into script editor?

Comment: @AY_91 use <style></style> tags to encapsulate the above code and paste the whole thing into a SEWP